# NumPy: counting sizes of row-wise intersections between two arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

I have 2 arrays filled by integers lower than 100. A number can't appear twice in a row.

- Array1: nrow=100 000 ; ncol=5
- Array2: nrow=50 000  ; ncol=5

I'd like to create a 3rd array *(Intersection)* with the number of similar element between each row of Array1 and each row of Array2.

```
def Intersection(array1, array2):
    Intersection = np.empty([ array1.shape[0]  , array2.shape[0] ], dtype=int8)
    for i in range(0, array1.shape[0]):
        for j in range(0, array2.shape[0]):
            Intersection[i,j] = len( set(array1[i,]).intersection(array2[j,]) )
    return Intersection
```

Here is an example:

```
array1 = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7,8,9,10,11] ])
array2 = np.array([[1, 3, 7, 20, 21], [1, 43, 104, 115, 116], [6,30,91,110,121] ])
#Expected result:
array([[2, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0]], dtype=int8)
```

This naive solution with nested loops is very slow. **How could I vectorize it ?**

Comment: Please could you post a small example showing two smaller arrays (e.g. 10x5) and your expected output in that case? That would really help clarify what you're asking for.

Comment: From googling "numpy.vectorize": "The vectorize function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop." http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html

Comment: @DSM I'm not saying this code works, but it's mine.
I'm a python beginner and I'm just trying to translate an idea into python code.

Comment: What do the entries of Array1 and Array2 look like? Are they bounded? Are they over a small set of unique integer values?

Comment: @ajcr I edited the description, It should answer your questions.

Comment: FYI: With inputs with lengths 100000 and 500000, your result will use 5 gigabytes of memory--assuming you make sure the data type is, say, `np.uint8`. It will be 40 gig. if you use the default `np.int64`.  If you expect most of those values to be 0, you might consider a sparse matrix representation.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser  I made a mistake in the description. The number of row of the 2nd matrix is 50 000 and not 500 000.

Comment: If I'm asuming the data type is int8, it's because the possible values are only 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 for the intersection array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one approach that takes on the order of a second for inputs of size 100000 and 50000:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse

def intersection_counts(x,y):
    # find the size of the input arrays
    n_x, n_d = x.shape
    n_y, n_d = y.shape

    # get a list of the unique values appearing in x and y, as well
    # as a list of inverse indices (see docs for np.unique)
    values, ix = np.unique(np.vstack((x,y)), return_inverse=True)
    n_unique = len(values)

    # reshape the inverse array. ix_x_hat will be an array the same size
    # as x, where ix_x_hat[i,j] gives the index of x[i,j] in values. That
    # is to say, values[ix_x_hat[i,j]] == x[i,j]
    ix_hat = ix.reshape(-1, n_d)
    ix_x_hat = ix_hat[:n_x]
    ix_y_hat = ix_hat[n_x:]

    # create a sparse matrix where entry [i,j] is 1 if and only if
    # row i of x contains values[j]
    x_hat = scipy.sparse.lil_matrix((n_x, n_unique), dtype=int)
    x_hat[np.arange(n_x)[:,None], ix_x_hat] = 1

    # create a sparse matrix where entry [i,j] is 1 if and only if
    # row i of y contains values[j]
    y_hat = scipy.sparse.lil_matrix((len(y), len(values)), dtype=int)
    y_hat[np.arange(n_y)[:,None], ix_y_hat] = 1

    # the dot product gives the solution
    return x_hat.dot(y_hat.T)
```

Here's the idea: suppose each entry of `x` and `y` takes a value in some small set, say, `values = [1,3,6,9,11,15,28,40]`. Consider a row of `x`:

```
x[0] = [11, 6, 40, 1, 3]
```

and a row of `y`:

```
y[0] = [3, 11, 6, 9, 15]
```

We can represent `x[0]` as a sparse vector that is the same length as `values`. The `i`th entry will be one if the `i`th value appears in `x`:

```
#          [1, 3, 6, 9,11,15,28,40]
x_hat[0] = [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
y_hat[0] = [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
```

How many elements are in the intersection between `x_hat` and `y_hat`? It's simply the dot product: 3. The above code does just this, but in batch.

The function works with sparse matrices, and the result is a sparse matrix, in order to save memory. Note that a dense 100000 x 50000 array of int32s is already 20 gigabytes, which may or may not exceed your RAM. See [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/sparse.html) for help on working with sparse arrays.

I tested the above code by generating arrays `x` and `y` with:

```
x = np.random.randint(0,1000,(100000,5))
y = np.random.randint(0,1000,(50000,5))
```

It completed in 2 seconds on my 5-year-old machine with 24GB of main memory. Here, `1000` serves as the range of possible values that `x` and `y` can take on. Making it smaller means that the matrices involved will be less sparse, and the code will take longer.

Comment: Yes, this is the case, the possible values are positive integers lower than 100.

Comment: This looks very interresting, but I don't understand the code. Could you please describe the main steps of the function ?

Comment: Could we do the same with a normal matrix instead of a parse matrix ?
**Because I need to know when the value is equal to 0.**

Comment: To obtain a dense matrix, you can use the `todense()` method on the result. That is, `intersection_counts(x,y).todense()`. Note, though, that this will result in *ton* of memory usage -- it's quite likely that *most* of the values are zero.

Comment: Memory is not a problem untill it's under 16GB. Howewer I really don't understand the code and the main steps of the function, could you please help me to understand it

Comment: I've added some comments to the code which should help. Unfortunately, 16GB of memory is not enough to represent the result as a dense matrix.

Comment: Thanks, this is very clear. I just don't understand why the execution will take longer if the range of values is smaller.
It should be the opposite, no ?

Comment: Just to ensure I understand your idea. If the dimension *(number of column)* is low and the range of possibilities is high, it's better to compare in a classic way the arrays, **but** if the dimension *(number of column)* is high and the range of possibilities is low, it's better to do your methodology (change the vectoriel space).
Did I correctly understand ?

Comment: I also have a question : why the dot product *(aka as scalar product)* is simpler to compute than the length of intersect between the 2 vectors ?

Comment: If the range of values is small, then the chance that row `x[i]` and row `y[j]` have an empty intersection is small. Then the matrices involved are not sparse, and multiplying them takes more time. In fact, we *want* the range of possibilities to be high so that the resulting matrices are very sparse. We use the sparse dot product here because it is vectorized, while numpy's intersection function is vectorized only for 1d arrays.

Comment: Unaware of the cross-posting, I gave a very similar solution here http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/71221

Comment: @moarningsun No worries. At a glance, it looks like your solution might be an improvement for the OP's specific case.